# SQL Query to get common records

Tags: sql, select, group-by, distinct, having

I have a table as below

```
ID  Username GroupID
1   venkat     2
2   venkat     3
3   ramu       1
4   ramu       2
```

Using the sql statement I want to retrieve all username's that are available in both the groupids 2,3

In this case only Venkat is the username that's available in both groupid 2 and 3

Kindly help me

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
SELECT userName
FROM tableA 
WHERE groupId IN (2, 3)
GROUP BY userName 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT groupId) = 2;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73141/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| USERNAME |
|----------|
|   venkat |
```

Comment: what if the a user is present twice for the same group id (for example user Pat is present twice for group id 2) - guess the present query wont work then

Comment: @Scorpion It will work because I had counted DISTINCT groupId for each user

Comment: @AmitAgrawal Check my fiddle demo. The Query will work

Comment: In the sample data the user venkat is repeating twice only, but we need only if the user is present in both the groups we can't limit the query to HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT groupId) = 2 because we dont know if it is 2 or 3 or someother number

Comment: @Tarak Check the fiddle demo. I had already aded where condition which will fetch only records for two groups (2, 3) and then I had used having clause with distinct groupId so it will work as per your need

Comment: 1. What is the purpose of the HAVING clause? 2. "groupid 2 and 3". Get rid of the HAVING clause and replace the IN with an AND.

Comment: @Scorpion Not a problem

Comment: @BillStidham Since there are 2 separate rows for the two groups, an `AND` won't do since it matches only if a single row contains both groupid's.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yep, I missed that. He'll need a self join too.

Answer (score 7):

An alternate approach using a plain `JOIN`;

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.username 
FROM MyTable t1 JOIN MyTable t2
  ON t1.username = t2.username AND t1.groupid=2 AND t2.groupid=3;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79d610/1).

Comment: its a much cleaner and better approach +1

Comment: What if i have multiple groupid's like 1,2,3,4,5..10 .. can you help me giving a much flexible query

Comment: @Tarak For that you have to use self join the table multilple times. Means if you have 5 Groups than you have join your table 5 times.