# SQL: find the non-manager employee IDs who joined all the projects

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlplus

Here are the schemas of given tables:

```
ProjectManager(ProjId, MgrId, StartDate, EndDate)
EmpProject(EmpId, ProjId, StartDate, EndDate)
```

In which "MgrId" is the same as "EmpId" just different naming. 
The question is **to find the non-manager employee IDs who joined all the projects.**

My thought is:
1. In table EmpProject, using "group by ProjId" to find EmpId which exists in all groups.
2. Then only select those empid that's not in ProjectManager.MgrId

Another thought is something similar to 
[SQL Query to get common records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761130/sql-query-to-get-common-records)

I've tried several ways but couldn't make progress.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this quick query. Basically, this filters out all Non-Managers by checking if the employee id is not present in the ProjectManager table

```
SELECT * 
FROM EmpProject
WHERE EmpId NOT IN (SELECT MgrId FROM ProjectManager)
```